# How can I get my current symfony installation run on a local server?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, localhost, ampps

I have been working on a `Symfony2` installation on a dedicated server for the past year and I'm finally trying to get it to work on my local server (*since I am spending more time meddling with the code lately*).

I've created a new database and imported it. Edited the `parameters.yml` file to contain all the info needed by local and ran php `composer.phar install`.
Ran `php app/console doctrine:schema:update`, clear cache, install assets and dumped assetics. No errors so far.

Now, when I go to the app.php file, I am getting this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Annotations\token_get_all() in [path]/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/TokenParser.php on line 56

I couldn't find an answer by searching (*could be because I am not sure what i am searching for*). Has anyone encountered this issue before and know how to fix it?

Regards,

Comment: What is your PHP version? You need to have the tokenizer extension of PHP activated (http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tokenizer.php).

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.3.29. The phpinfo.cgi shows that I have the tokenizer enabled, but when I run web/config.php, it says I am missing both tokenizer and ctype which are both enabled as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the PHP tokenizer extension enabled? Check [the Symfony requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html) for more information.

In Ubuntu 14.04 you could install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: The phpinfo.cgi shows that I have the tokenizer enabled, but when I run web/config.php, it says I am missing both tokenizer and ctype which are both enabled as far as I can tell.

Comment: I changed AMPPS config to use php5.5 and enable the extension tokenizer. I am not sure why it was showing as enabled before when it wasn't, but thanks.